# djongo ArrayField not appearing in Django Admin

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am following the official docs of Djongo mapper => https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/ to add **Array Fields** to my Model, but unfortunately even after adding the **Array Fields** as stated in the docs I am unable to see them in the below view shown in the docs.

[image]

### Here is the Model defined by me.

```
from djongo import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EventModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()

    authors = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Author,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self._id
```

Here is the generated **Django Admin view** based on my Models, which is no way similar to the one shown in docs here.

https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: I am using djongo==1.3.3 to develop my django rest api application.

Comment: I'm facing a [similar problem with ArrayField](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67895534/2989289), now with `djongo==1.3.6`

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?