# Using Djongo's ArrayField at Django Admin

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-admin, djongo

[Djongo](https://www.djongomapper.com/) is a *Django and MongoDB database connector* witch brings, beside others, the [ArrayField](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/blob/1881e96f4845eb515addcc52eb3e80e70ad23de9/djongo/models/fields.py#L301) to Django Models. It allows one to store multiple instances of an other `djongo.models.Model` in an unique [MongoDB Array field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/) inside a document related with the `Model` that has the `Arrayfield`

As described in source documentation:
"The model of the container must be declared as abstract, thus should not be treated as a collection of its own."

As well as in [djongo's site tutorials](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/#using-arrayfield-in-django-admin)
"In case you don’t plan on using your embedded model as a standalone model (which means it will always be embedded inside a parent model) you should add the `class Meta` and `abstract = True` This way Djongo will never register this model as an actual model."

This way I made:

```py
# models.py

class Contact(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('key',)

class Person(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    ...
    contact = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Contact,
        model_form_class=ContactForm,
    )

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

```py
# admin.py

admin.site.register(Person)
```

```sh
$ pip freeze
Django==3.2.4
djongo==1.3.6
pymongo==3.11.4
...
```

However when I try to add a `Person` through Django Admin (in /admin/<app>/person/add/) I receive the error **Abstract models cannot be instantiated** from `.../django/db/models/base.py`

This seems inconsistent with Djongo's description. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you also share your form?

Comment: Djongo's `ArrayField` doesn't require a `FormModel`, as described in its site. Thus I didn't use any

Comment: I see. I was curious to see how this model and its form is registered to the admin (and what form it is using) because this issue seems to be caused by the form. Maybe worth a try to customise it and see what's going on

Comment: I've added the example using `ModelForm` as suggested by Djongo. But the issue persists

Comment: Downgrading Django to 3.1.12 seems to work

Comment: thans, it worked for me, when i Downgrad my django version from latest to 3.1.12